# References for harmonic oscillator with memory

Tags: resource-recommendations, integration, oscillators, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

I'm reading Neu's "Singular Perturbation in the Physical Sciences" and in problems 1.1 and 1.2 he defines systems that "have memory" as the the variant of the harmonic oscillator

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\ddot{x}(t-\epsilon s)ds + x(t) = 0.
$$

This doesn't seem to fit in the category o delayed equation since the delay is in the derivative. Also, in the book the author do not gives a direct reference to this kind of problem. Can someone point me to references regarding this kind of problem?

Comment: The second derivative is proportional to a force (if you think of it as a mechanical equation). Delaying the position of a system and then calculating a force as the second derivative is equivalent to delaying the force itself (even though it would result in slightly different physical systems). Maybe that is why the author thinks of it as a delay equation?

Comment: He does not say it is a delayed equation, this for my part. Since I could not find any resource with the "HO with memory" I though it might be considered a delayed system, but didn't find anything either.

Comment: Did you try to search for "delay harmonic oscillator"? I remember that there was quite a bit of interest in these systems in the 1990s or so. Another term to look for is "synergetics". Those researchers wrote a lot about non-linear time delayed systems back then and I would assume that part of that analysis must have involved finding the spectra of the linearized system.

Comment: Humm thank you, I'll search for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm reading Neu's "Singular Perturbation in the Physical Sciences" and in problems 1.1 and 1.2 he defines systems that "have memory" as the the variant of the harmonic oscillator

Systems that "have memory" tend to exhibit [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Further_reading). The linked page has references in the "further reading" section.

> $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-s}\ddot{x}(t-\epsilon s)ds + x(t) = 0.
> $$

An an initial note, the units don't seem to make sense. Since $s$ is in the exponent it should be dimensionless, but also since the dimensions of $ds$ times the second time derivative of $x$ are the same units as $x$, this implies that $s$ should have units of time squared. This is inconsistent, so there apparently is some dimensionful constant that has been set to one somewhere... probably you would want to insert something like an $\omega_0^2$ multiplying the bare $x(t)$ term, which would allow $\epsilon$ to have units of time and allow $s$ to be unitless.

> ... Can someone point me to references regarding this kind of problem ?

If you are looking for references regarding "hysteresis," see the link above.

If you are looking for general help solving this integral equation, I would probably start by considering the Fourier transform:
$$
x(t)\equiv \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\tilde x(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\;,
$$
and see where that gets you. (Likely get you something like $x(t)=e^{-\alpha t}\cos(\beta t + \gamma)$, for some constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$.)

Comment: I was thinking more about some mathematical physics approach, but this material of hysteresis seems highly correlated with control (my area), thank you very much